# python unittest error indicating No overdrafts

Tags: python, oop, python-unittest

I have been working on a test and each time I run my code it displays the error code below:

> test_savings_account_cannot_withdraw_more_than_current_balance Failure
>   in line 48, in
>   test_savings_account_cannot_withdraw_more_than_current_balance
>   self.assertEquals(message, 'Cannot withdraw beyond the current account
>   balance', msg='No overdrafts') AssertionError: No overdrafts**

```
class BankAccount:
    def withdraw(self):
        pass

    def deposit(self):
        pass

class SavingsAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, balance=500):
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        if (amount <= 0):
            return "Invalid deposit amount"
        else:
            self.balance += amount
        return self.balance

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if(amount <= 0):
            return "Invalid withdraw amount"
        elif(self.balance <= 500):
            return "Cannot withdraw beyond the minimum account balance"
        elif(amount > self.balance):
            return "Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance"
        else:
            self.balance -= amount
            return self.balance    


class CurrentAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, balance=0):
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        if (amount <= 0):
            return "Invalid deposit amount"
        else:
            self.balance += amount
            return self.balance

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if (amount <= 0):
            return "Invalid withdraw amount"
        elif (amount >= self.balance):
            return "Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance"
        else:
        self.balance -= amount
        return self.balance
```

and the unittest is

```
import unittest

class CurrentAccountTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.ca = CurrentAccount()

    def tearDown(self):
        del self.ca

    def test_current_account_is_instance_of_bank_account(self):
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(self.ca, BankAccount), msg='CurrentAccount is not a subclass of BankAccount')

    def test_current_account_can_deposit_valid_amounts(self):
        balance = self.ca.deposit(1500)
        self.assertEquals(balance, 1500)

    def test_current_account_cannot_withdraw_more_than_current_balance(self):
      message = self.ca.withdraw(1500)
      self.assertEquals(message, 'Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance', msg='No overdrafts')

    def test_current_account_can_withdraw_valid_cash_amounts(self):
        self.ca.deposit(23001)
        self.ca.withdraw(437)
        self.assertEquals(self.ca.balance, 22564, msg='Incorrect balance after withdrawal')

class SavingsAccountTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
self.sa = SavingsAccount()

    def tearDown(self):
      del self.sa

    def test_savings_account_is_instance_of_bank_account(self):
      self.assertTrue(isinstance(self.sa, BankAccount), msg='SavingsAccount is not a subclass of BankAccount')

    def test_savings_account_can_deposit_valid_amounts(self):
      init_balance = self.sa.balance
      balance = self.sa.deposit(1500)
      self.assertEquals(balance, (1500 + init_balance), msg='Balance does not match deposit')

    def test_savings_account_cannot_withdraw_more_than_current_balance(self):
      message = self.sa.withdraw(1500)
      self.assertEquals(message, 'Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance', msg='No overdrafts')

    def test_savings_account_can_withdraw_valid_amounts_successfully(self):
      self.sa.deposit(2300)
      self.sa.withdraw(543)
      self.assertEquals(2257, self.sa.balance, msg="Incorrect balance after withdrawal")
```

Comment: You need to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Because your default balance is 500, and your amount is 1500, so the string you it would return is "Cannot withdraw beyond the minimum account balance" and not the one you expect "Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance"